# lexical analyser correct output but pointer "filename" contains wrong name

Tags: c, regex, stack, flex-lexer

The purpose of this code is to read the following txts(d.txt,e.txt,f.txt) and do the actions that are required in order to put the alphabet with the correct order into the output.txt. The code suppose to work since in output.txt i get the correct results but there is a problem with the testing i did using the printf (it's at the end of newfile function). In order to run i give as input d.txt and output.txt.
It should print

```
top->prev points to file :d
top->prev points to file :e
```

but instead it prints the following and i can't find the reason

```
top->prev points to file :d
top->prev points to file :f
```

d.txt:

```
abc
#include e.txt
mno
```

e.txt:

```
def
#include f.txt
jkl
```

f.txt:

```
ghi
```

code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct yyfilebuffer{
    YY_BUFFER_STATE bs;
    struct yyfilebuffer *prev;
    FILE *f;
    char *filename;
}*top;

int i;
char temporal[7];
void newfile(char *filename);
void popfile();
void create();
%}

%s INC
%option noyywrap
%%
"#include " {BEGIN INC;}
<INC>.*$ {for(i=1;i<strlen(yytext)-2;i++)
          {
            temporal[i-1]=yytext[i];
          }
          newfile(temporal);
          BEGIN INITIAL;
         }

<<EOF>> {popfile();
        BEGIN INITIAL;
        }
%%

void main(int argc,int **argv)
{
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
        printf("\nUsage yybuferstate <filenamein> <filenameout>");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        create();
        newfile(argv[1]);
        yyout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        yylex();
    }
    system("pause");
}

void create()
{
    top = NULL;
}

void newfile(char *filename)
{
    struct yyfilebuffer *newptr;
    if(top == NULL)
    {
        newptr = malloc(1*sizeof(struct yyfilebuffer));
        newptr->prev = NULL;
        newptr->filename = filename;
        newptr->f = fopen(filename,"r");
        newptr->bs = yy_create_buffer(newptr->f, YY_BUF_SIZE);
        top = newptr;
        yy_switch_to_buffer(top->bs);
    }
    else
    {
        newptr = malloc(1*sizeof(struct yyfilebuffer));
        newptr->prev = top;
        newptr->filename = filename;
        newptr->f = fopen(filename,"r");
        newptr->bs = yy_create_buffer(newptr->f, YY_BUF_SIZE);
        top = newptr;
        yy_switch_to_buffer(top->bs);   //edw
    }
    if(top->prev != NULL)
    {
        printf("top->prev points to file : %s\n",top->prev->filename);
    }
}

void popfile()
{
    struct yyfilebuffer *temp;      
    temp = NULL;
    if(top->prev == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Trying to pop from empty stack");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = top;
        top = temp->prev;
        yy_switch_to_buffer(top->bs);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in C.

Comment: I forgot to edit the void *.  What do you mean by "cast the result of malloc" ?

Comment: Read what a cast is in C.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about how you manage memory, remembering that C does not really have a string type in the way you might be used to from other languages.

You define a global variable:

```
char temporal[7];
```

(which has an odd name, since globals are anything but temporary), and then fill in its value in your lexer:

```
for(i=1;i<strlen(yytext)-2;i++) {
        temporal[i-1]=yytext[i];
}
```

There are at least three problems with the above code:

1. `temporal` only has room for a six-character filename, but nowhere do you check to make sure that `yyleng` is not greater than 6. If it is, you will overwrite random memory. (The flex-generated scanner sets `yyleng` to the length of the token whose starting address is `yytext`. So you might as well use that value instead of computing `strlen(yytext)`, which involves a scan over the text.)
2. You never null-terminate `temporal`. That's OK the first time, because it has static lifetime and will therefore be filled with zeros at program initialization. But the second and subsequent times you are counting on the new filename to not be shorter than the previous one; otherwise, you'll end up with part of the previous name at the end of the new name.
3. You could have made much better use of the standard C library. Although for reasons I will note below, this does not solve the problem you observe, it would have been better to use the following instead of the loop, *after checking* that `yyleng` is not too big:

   ```
   memcpy(temporal, yytext + 1, yyleng - 2); /* Copy the filename */
   temporal[yyleng - 2] = '\0';              /* NUL-terminate the copy */
   ```

Once you make the copy in `temporal`, you give that to `newfile`:

```
newfile(temporal);
```

And in `newfile`, what we see is:

```
newptr->filename = filename;
```

That *does not copy filename*. The call to `newfile` passed the address of `temporal` as an argument, so within `newfile`, the value of the parameter `filename` is the address of `temporal`. You then store that address in `newptr->filename`, so `newptr->filename` is also the address of `temporal`.

But, as noted above, `temporal` is not temporary. It is a global variable whose lifetime is the entire lifetime of the program. So the next time your lexical scanner encounters an `include` directive, it will put it into `temporal`, overwriting the previous contents. So what then happens to the `filename` member in the `yyfilebuffer` structure? Answer: nothing. It still points to the same place, `temporal`, but the contents of that place have changed. So when you later print out the contents of the string pointed to by that `filename` field, you'll get a different string from the one which happened to be in `temporal` when you first created that `yyfilebuffer` structure.

On the whole, you'll find it easier to manage memory if `newfile` and `popfile` "own" the memory in the filebuffer stack. That means that `newfile` should make a copy of its argument into freshly-allocated storage, and `popfile` should free that storage, since it is no longer needed. If `newfile` makes a copy, then it is not necessary for the lexical-scanner action which calls `newfile` to make a copy; it is only necessary for it to make sure that the string is correctly NUL-terminated when it calls `newfile`.

In short, the code might look like this:

```
/* Changed parameter to const, since we are not modifying its contents */
void newfile(const char *filename) { 
    /* Eliminated this check as obviously unnecessary: if(top == NULL) */
    struct yyfilebuffer *newptr = malloc(sizeof(struct yyfilebuffer));
    newptr->prev = top;
    // Here we copy filename. Since I suspect that you are on Windows,
    // I'll write it out in full. Normally, I'd use strdup.
    newptr->filename = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
    strcpy(newptr->filename, filename);
    newptr->f = fopen(filename,"r");
    newptr->bs = yy_create_buffer(newptr->f, YY_BUF_SIZE);
    top = newptr;
    yy_switch_to_buffer(top->bs);   //edw

    if(top->prev != NULL) {
        printf("top->prev points to file : %s\n",top->prev->filename);
    }
}

void popfile() {
    if(top->prev == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : Trying to pop from empty stack\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct yyfilebuffer temp = top;
    top = temp->prev;
    /* Reclaim memory */
    free(temp->filename);
    free(temp);

    yy_switch_to_buffer(top->bs);
    system("pause");
}
```

Now that `newfile` takes ownership of the string passed to it, we no longer need to make a copy. Since the action clearly indicates that you expect the argument to the `#include` to be something like a C `#include` directive (surrounded either by `"..."` or `<...>`), it is better to make that explicit:

```
<INC>\".+\"$|"<".+">"$ {
           /* NUL-terminate the filename by overwriting the trailing "*/
           yytext[yyleng - 1] = '\0';
           newfile(yytext + 1);
           BEGIN INITIAL;
         }
```

Comment: That was very educational and also solved my problem. Thank you very much.